# Embed excel sheet into WPF window

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, vba

I have a WPF application that opens excel macros with the code

```
Process.Start("C:\\My Library\\MyFile.xlsm");
```

Now I want to run this sheet inside the WPF application. Is there any chance to open the excel sheet in a new WPF window, and run the macro?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible out of the box, to achieve such thing. You need to dig deep in msdn documentations about controls and libraries and how to reuse them.

So, I will suggest that you can use a third party "excel style" control.

You can check in this tutorial with a free tool - [Spreadsheet Control](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691749/Free-NET-Spreadsheet-Control).